Error when importing typescript modules from my custom library without specifying extension
reproducible example: https://github.com/croraf/typescript-import-issue

I've published my_library which has this in package.json:
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./index.ts"
    },
    "./lib/*": {
      "import": "./lib/*"
    }
  },

I installed it as a dependency in my application and I try to import a module with import TextField2 from 'my_library/lib/TextField2'. At runtime it works (Vite bundler). But the TS gives the error:

Cannot find module 'my_library/lib/TextField2' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

But if I add the extension it works import TextField2 from 'my_library/lib/TextField2.tsx'

Now, in my_library I also do the re-export of the module in index.ts.
import TextField2 from "./lib/TextField2";
export {
  TextField2,
};

And when importing it from my application like import {TextField2} from 'my_library' the TS recognition works and there is no error.

tsconfig.json in the calling code
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [ "ES2023", "DOM", ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "allowJs": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": [ "src" ],
  "references": [ { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" } ]
}


So solved? Didn't get if the last is sufficient for you

It is not. The last is kind of a workaround, but not the solution.

Can you share your tsconfig.json?

Will update the post. In the meantime here is the calling application on my library that doesn't produce TS error https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/46d579?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts%3A3%2C54
Still when autocomplete it does not provide both variants, but it doesnt error out.
I selected Vite template in Codesandbox and it gave me this template.

Ok, the issue is in this configuration, when I replace it with the one from the sandbox it works ok.

Had the feeling

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
